# Possible ground loop trouble with detector design

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, ground-loop

I am a physics student trying to build a proportional counter. I am having huge trouble dealing with possible ground loops in designing the system.

The current design is attached below. Could anyone point out where I got it wrong?

[image: Current design]

Schematic of the preamplifier:
[image: Schematic of the preamplifier]

The capacitance of the proportional counter is around 400 pF.

Schematic of the isolated DC/DC converter:
[image: Schematic of the isolated DC/DC converter]

Schematic of the high voltage DC/DC converter:
[image: Schematic of the high voltage DC/DC converter]

The high voltage is intended to run at around 600 V.

Signal output from the preamplifier with everything connected except high voltage:
[image: Signal output from the preamplifier with everything connected except high voltage]

Weird unwanted tail pulses appear in the output once the high voltage connected:
[image: Weird unwanted tail pulses appear in the output once the high voltage connected]

Also appear as negative pulses:
[image: Also appear as negative pulses]

Correct signal output I am looking for:
[image: Correct signal output I am looking for]

I tested the preamplifier and the power supply (without high voltage) with a function generator and they behave fine. The problem arises when I connect everything to the detector with the high voltage enabled. The signal output from the preamplifier has a seemingly random tail pulse (~ 10 Hz, ~2 ms rise time, ~20 ms decay time) that completely masks the tail pulse signal from the detector (~ns rise time, ~200 μs decay time.) The output from the high voltage alone is stable with less than 10 mV ripple noise.

P.S. Further investigation indicates that the high voltage power supply might be the culprit. What is the proper way to monitor the behavior of the high voltage power supply under load using an oscilloscope? Could I just use a voltage divider to safely monitor its behavior?

Comment: Can you post the schematics of the sub assemblies?

Comment: @LiorBilia Thanks for your reply, see the updated post for schematics.

Comment: Welcome! Please post oscillograms of your mystery 10 Hz signal.

Comment: What do you mean by insulated and non-insulated connector?  Is the latter a normal coax connector with the shell connected to a metal chassis?  So that would make the former a coax connector with the shell insulated from the chassis?

Comment: Does the high voltage go to the detector?

Comment: @SteveSh Yes sir, that is what I meant by the insulated/non-insulated connector. And yes, the high voltage goes into the detector through the "bias section" presented in the preamplifier schematic.

Comment: @winny Thanks for your reply, see the updated post for signal output.

Comment: "Could I just use a voltage divider to safely monitor its behavior?"  Yes.  But you need be careful that you're not creating an RC filter that will attenuate/hide the disturbance.

Comment: @SteveSh Ah! Thank you for pointing this out, I did not think of this.

Comment: I'd check the 5V regulator output and HV output. The HV DC/DC converter can draw up to 400 mA at full load and the 78L05 is spec'ed at 100 mA. When the circuit is first powered up, there is 330k from the "Bias" node to essentially ground through the uncharged 10-nF cap. This results in ~1.8 mA, which is more than the 1-mA max output spec for the converter. Maybe change the 330k resistors to something larger to stay below 1 mA. Also on power up, there is going to be close to full bias voltage going to the op amp's pin 2 through the 10-nF cap as it charges up. Try to clamp this with a diode.

Comment: Something I should have asked early, but does the "unwanted tail pulse" always hide/blank the desired signal, or is this something that only happens on occasion?

Comment: @SteveSh I should be more specific. The unwanted tail pulse happens seemingly random, about once every 3~10 seconds. When its not there, the output signal from the preamp behaves as intended. When the unwanted tail pulse appears, the output signal would ride on top of the tail pulse.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a difference.  So something is disturbing the HV output (at least at the detector), not related to any "detection" by the detector?

Comment: @SteveSh Yes, I agree. Now I tried to disconnect the preamp with the high voltage enabled, and I will still see these unwanted signal. I am thinking adding some decoupling capacitors on the "bias" node of the preamplifier, would this help? Also, where should I put them if this might work? I am thinking adding some next to the 10nF, right after the first 330k resistor.

Comment: @Just_visiting Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I did not think about the current draw situation. I will try that now. Could you elaborate a bit more on "clamp with a diode"? I have very little experience with this.

Comment: Put a diode with the anode on pin 2 and the cathode on ground. This will limit the voltage to about 0.6 VDC. One tricky thing is that the diode will still conduct forward current after the cap has charged, and this will result in a DC offset at the op-amp's output. Hopefully not a problem since you can AC couple the output and remove the DC. I think most "vanilla" diodes should have low forward current -- maybe 10 nA, resulting in 1 VDC offset -- but I'm not certain about this. Also, you might want to use the bigger 7805 (not "L" version) since it can handle more current and power.

Comment: @Just_visiting Thanks! The DC offset won't be a problem since it will be fed into an ac-coupled shaping amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your design: you might want to add a 10 kΩ resistor in series with your adjustment potentiometer. You don't want to short Vref to ground.

Monitoring high voltage with an oscilloscope: There are high voltage differential probes available from various vendors. They provide a safe method to probe such voltages.

EMC: Depending on the source of noise, few options exist to mitigate it in such a setup: ferrite beads, feed through capacitors or better PSU.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will look into these options.

Comment: Besides the 10K  resistor, you also might want to add a decoupling cap to the Vadj input of the high voltage chip.  Any kind of noise on that input will disturb the high voltage output.

Comment: @SteveSh Thanks for pointing it out, I will do so.